# SELECT age and earliest date from table query

Tags: sqlite

```
 CREATE TABLE funcionario
  ( 
   idFuncionario    varchar2(5) not null,
   nome varchar2(50)    not null,
   remuneracao  varchar2(10)    not null,
   id   varchar2(5) not null,
   datanasc date    not null,
   morada   varchar(50) not null,
   tipoFuncionario varchar(20),
   idDepartamento   varchar2(5) REFERENCES departamento(idDepartamento),

   CONSTRAINT funcionario_pk PRIMARY KEY (idFuncionario)
 );
```

Hello there, I have this table and I want to find the earliest date and the age from every client (another table). 
I've tried this:
    SELECT nome, remuneracao, max(dataNasc) from funcionario

and it actually prints the min date but I think it orders it by using the day and not the year. 
For the age I'm struggling and I can't really figure that out.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Kinda regards

Comment: Can you add another table structure also and your query which is getting min date.

Comment: `varchar2` Negative one, didn't even read the `sql-server` tag: *Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system. Use this tag for all SQL Server editions including Compact, Express, Azure, Fast-track and PDW. Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.).*

Answer (score 0):

Please try below to queries;

```
// To find the oldest age by number of days
SELECT nome, remuneracao, MAX(DATEDIFF(NOW(), remuneracao)) AS max_age_in_days  FROM funcionario;

// To find the oldest age by number of years
SELECT nome, remuneracao, MAX(DATEDIFF(NOW(), remuneracao)/365)) AS max_age_in_years  FROM funcionario;
```

Comment: It says no such function: NOW

Comment: Can you please let me know which database you using MySQL or MS SQL or SQL Lite?  Also try **CURDATE()** instead

Answer (score 0):

This is none too clear -

```
SELECT nome, remuneracao, max(dataNasc) from funcionario
```

appears to give you their name, salary and latest (not earliest) date of birth.

Try MIN instead of MAX for starters. For example

```
SELECT nome, remuneracao, min(dataNasc), datediff(year,min(dataNasc), getdate()) from funcionario
```

Answer (score 0):

*the earliest date* --> **MIN** date

```
SELECT
    nome, id, min(datanasc), ((julianday('now') - julianday(datanasc))/365) as Age
FROM
    funcionario
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e3d55/12)

Comment: it says NOW function does not exist. I'm using Database Browser

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out how to **find the earliest/oldest date and the age**. Thank you to everyone that tried to help. For those who might have the same problem, a quick explanation/ solution.

In SQLite functions like DATEDIFF and NOW() do not exist, to calculate and manipulate date information you should use date() (which has the same effect as now). To get the age using a birthdate (my dataNasc field above) , you can simply do the subtraction.
Plus, in order to work and get the correct min or max date you must write your date in YY-MM-DD format.

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards